# Changing margin-top responsively

Tags: css

I'm trying to format a HTML DIV in a way that the margin-top is set responsively based on the div's height: **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79cyhte7/)**

There's another div inside the wrapper, that has a `display: none` set to it, but it may change when the user inputs a wrong password. Thing is, there is a div below that it's being pushed down when `display: content` is set to the second div. I want the content of the page to responsively go upwards instead of downwards.

How's now:
[image]

How it should be:
[image]

Comment: can you make a quick paint drawing of what you're currently gettings vs what you want?

Comment: Sure, check it out edited. Thing is, I want the margin-top to respond when the content is large enough to stretch the page.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like you're trying to just keep things centered vertically in the view rather than have things move down as more content is displayed.  Is that the case?  If so just use flexbox containers with centered content and forget about the top-margin.

Comment: Well, we need to make sure it works on IE10, so flexbox is not a good use for it.

Comment: IE10 partially supports flexbox.  Granted there are some bugs, but you can work around them for something this small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example, your goal and your preference to avoid flexbox due to IE10, I think your best option is to use `display:table` for this container.

With this, you have the ability to use `vertical-align` properties in the "table-cell".

Check the example below.  I added a toggle button to show/hide your captcha for demo purposes.  **May want to view it full screen to get the effect.**

```js
$("#toggle").on('click', function() {
  $(".captcha").toggle();
});
```

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
.outer-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eeeeee;
  display: table;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: inherit;
}

.login-wrapper {
  background-color: #172238;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.captcha{
  margin-top: 250px;
  display: content; // This one changes
}

.homologation-line {
  min-width: 200px;
  background-color: #ffd800;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
}

#toggle {
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">toggle captcha</button>
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <div class="login-wrapper">
        <p>Login</p>
        <div class="captcha">
          ENTER THE DIGITS:
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="homologation-line">
       HOMOLOGATION
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you change the exact margin-top of another element like this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  The point of a solution like this is to center the content in an area so that its always visible to the user regardless of size so you don't have to rely on things like margin and breakpoints. Because when taking that approach you're relying on assumptions.